# Incorrect total of sum calculation

Tags: java

I'm trying to solve this question:

> Write a Java program that reads a filename from the user. The file is expected to contain a maximum of 20 integers.
>   Declare an array with the size 20. Read all the values from the file and store them in the array. Take note that there
>   can be any number of integers in the file. Lastly, calculate and display the sum of all integers stored in the array.
>   Use exception handling to detect:
>
> - Improper inputs from the file where a non-integer is read
> - Using of invalid array index
> - Invalid filename where he file does not exist

My problem currently is the incorrect sum. Here is my code

```
package labtask.pkg10;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class task2 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       int integers[] = new int[20];
       Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
       int sum = 0;
       int num = 0;
       String filename;
       System.out.println("enter the file name ");
       filename = read.next();

       try {
           File file = new File(filename);
           Scanner inputFile = null;
           inputFile = new Scanner(file);

           int i = 0;
           while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
               num = Integer.parseInt(inputFile.next());

               integers[i] = num;
           }

           for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
               sum += num;
           }
           System.out.println("sum are : " + sum);
       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           System.out.println("file not found");
       } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
           System.out.println("please enter only integer number");
       }
   }
}
```

and my text file:

```
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
12
23
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
```

I get the following output:

> enter the file name
>   gg.txt
>   sum are : 40
>   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)

Why isn't the sum counted correctly?

Comment: Why do you expect the sum to be correct? Your code explicitly ignores the array and just sums up `num`.

Comment: Hint: the one and **only real** answer here: when your code behaves unexpectedly, don't turn to other people for help (at least not as first step). Instead: use **trace** statements to make it *more clear* what your code is doing. In other words: if you dont understand what your code is doing, make that observable to you. So, trace stuff, or learn to use a debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Eran already answered your question, I want to come up with a solution for everybody else, not having the requirement of using a int[]. Exception handling needs to be added, but let's assume the file will be ok for the sake of example - the following would be your complete "summing logic":

```
Integer sum = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("numbs.txt"))
    .stream()
    .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
    .sum();
System.out.println(sum); // 71
```

Answer (score 5):

You are adding the last input 20 times to the sum instead of adding the different numbers.

Change your code to:

```
while(inputFile.hasNext())
{
    num = Integer.parseInt(inputFile.next());

    integers[i++] = num;
}

for (int x = 0 ; x<integers.length; x ++)
{
    sum += integers[x];
}
```

Or just use a single loop:

```
while(inputFile.hasNext()) {
    num = Integer.parseInt(inputFile.next());
    integers[i++] = num;
    sum += num;
}
```

Comment: With a single loop, the integer array isn't even needed anymore. And it limits the risk of having a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException if a bigger file is used.

Comment: @Eran one more question .. why the two loop don't wont but single loop work ?

Comment: @sozai Because the index of the loop was wrong - should be `x` instead of `i` - fixed now, and also because `i` wasn't incremented in the while loop.

Comment: also pay attention that your array size is 20 add if the file would contain more numbers you're program would crush. think about using a for loop instead of the while

Comment: Hi @sozai, if this answer solved your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).  For instructions on how to do so, please see [this help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).